# how to convert javascipt in the protractor

Tags: protractor

I want to convert $x("//*[@class='file-folder-breadcrumbs-item-part name']")[1].innerText; statement in the protractor compatible running statement.
I am new in automation testing please help.

Comment: What tried. What best results. What's protractor

Comment: Protractor is a automation testing framework. I am new in this field and I am stuck here from last 7 days. Please help.

I can get value when I tried this on console but not able to convert in this JavaScript code in protractor code.

Below is HTML

Comment: <div class="file-folder-breadcrumbs-child-panel ng-hide" ng-show="isExpanded(root.full)">
     <!-- ngRepeat: child in root.nodes -->
        <div ng-repeat="child in root.nodes" class="ui-state-default filedrop file-folder-breadcrumbs-item-child ng-scope" ng-click="navigateToChild($event, child, root)">
           <span class="ng-binding">TestFolder</span>
         </div>
     <!-- end ngRepeat: child in root.nodes -->
 </div>

Comment: please update your Question. add your last source.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get span value which has ng-bulding class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67613857/how-to-get-span-value-which-has-ng-bulding-class)