# How to get span value which has ng-bulding class?

Tags: protractor

I can get value when I tried this on console using:

```
$x("//*[@class='file-folder-breadcrumbs-item-part name']")[1].innerText;
```

or

```
document.querySelector("[ng-if='currentPathNodes.length']").innerText;
```

but not able to convert in this JavaScript code in Protractor code.

Below is HTML

```
<div class="file-folder-breadcrumbs-child-panel ng-hide" ng-shenter image ow="isExpanded(root.full)">
     <!-- ngRepeat: child in root.nodes -->
        <div ng-repeat="child in root.nodes" class="ui-state-default filedrop file-folder-breadcrumbs-item-child ng-scope" ng-click="navigateToChild($event, child, root)">
           <span class="ng-binding">TestFolder</span>
         </div>
     <!-- end ngRepeat: child in root.nodes -->
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: html is missing, the question is not formatted and you didn't mention what you tried to do in protractor

Comment: is not it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67612929/how-to-convert-javascipt-in-the-protractor the same question?

Comment: I need ans. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
const breadcrumbPart = element.all(by.css('.file-folder-breadcrumbs-item-part.name').first();

const myText = await breadcrumbPart.getText();

// console.log(myText);
expect(myText).toEqual('something');
```

Or synchronous solution:

```
const breadcrumbPart = element.all(by.css('.file-folder-breadcrumbs-item-part.name').first();

breadcrumbPart.getText().then(myText => {
  // console.log(myText);
  expect(myText).toEqual('something');
});
```

Comment: 13:47:11] E/launcher - Error: /home/rsuc/dev/ConX/telematics/test/protractor/tests/files.spec.js:54
    const myText = await breadcrumbPart.getText();
                   ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:138:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:199:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)

Comment: See Edit for synchronous solution